# Are there ever any animals featured that aren't Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon

Out of the Pokémon episodes that I have seen, I do not remember ever seeing an animal that wasn't a Pokémon. I have also not heard of animals being present in Pokémon.

Which lead me to wonder: Are there ever any animals that aren't Pokémon present in any episode or Pokémon manga?

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/127252/4918 "Do regular animals exist in the Pokémon universe?" on Science Fiction & Fantasy SE.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Gastly's Pokédex entry for Fire Red it states

> a being that exists as a thin gas. It can topple an Indian elephant by enveloping the prey in two seconds.

Fish are also seen in the episode Pokémon Shipwreck:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

When researching to see if there has ever been an animal featured that isn't a Pokémon in a scene or Manga I came across this on Bulbapedia's article [*Animals in the Pokémon world*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Animals_in_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world):

> Real-world animals have been mentioned a number of times to exist in the world of Pokémon. Most often, they are mentioned in relation to a Pokémon category. For example, Pikachu is known as the "Mouse Pokémon" and was directly referred to in the anime as an "electric mouse", hinting that real-world mice exist in the Pokémon world. Other than this, all other mentions of animals are rare.

There was also this image:
[image: Let's have a Festival Pokémon Picture Book]

Which clearly shows a dog. However, this is the only image I could find of an animal that isn't a Pokémon.

Comment: Actually, "electric mouse Pokémon" doesn't exactly imply there are real-world mice in-universe. Pikachu isn't the only mouse Pokémon, and also not the only electric one. Saying "a Pikachu is a mouse Pokémon", would be like saying "a Labrador is a dog animal". It's kinda redundant, but it doesn't really have any deeper meaning to it either.

Answer (score 15):

There's a pretty comprehensive list of animal occurences in pokemon on Bulbapedia [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Animals_in_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world).

Examples:

- In "Ash Catches a Pokémon" Pidgeotto is seen eating a regular worm
  before being captured by Ash.
- In "The Water Flowers of Cerulean City" fish can be seen in the fish tanks inside the Gym
- In "Battle Aboard the St. Anne" a cooked lobster can be seen as food served on the ship.

Answer (score 5):

Several examples exist in early episodes. Shortly before Ash catches Pidgeotto, it [eats a worm](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP003), possibly the smallest non-Pokémon animal the anime ever showed. References to such species lasted longer than their appearances. In a [much later episode](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP168), Ash mentions catfish.

Answer (score 1):

In season 1 episode 20 there is this, I don't think it's a Pokémon, but can't say what animal this is:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking of the very same episode, it's a mongoose which is snakes' natural rival

Answer (score 1):

On the Pokèmon card Inkay (069/198) rapid strike, it is holding a roll of cheese. This has a picture of a cow on it.

ALSO, on the Peony 150/198 supporter card, there is a wood carving of (reindeer, mouse, caribou, or something) next to the closest house.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit curious why you deleted [your previous answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/66010/2516). Note that you can always [edit] your post to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the episodes in the indigo league they eat muskrat kebabs and say themselves it's muskrat. Don't know which episode though